# Declaring a function on $rootScope that knows to refer to the scope it's called from

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I want to define my own global $rootScope function called `log`, I want it to support accessing the scope where it's called, is there a `this` or another secret keyword that I can use in HTML to refer to the current scope?

So, I want to do something like this:

```
{{ log("some log", $this) }}
```

And then to be able in the log function to do something like this:

```
$rootScope.log = function(msg, scope)
{
    //access scope.whatever 
}
```

Is this possible or are there other ways to refer to the scope? I know `callee` is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the calling scope using `this` in your function code without passing it as an argument.

```
{{ log("some log") }}

$rootScope.log = function(msg)
{
    // this refers to the calling scope
}
```